# Azure DevOps Server 2019 - Create pipeline - No GitHub yaml option in Where is Your Code

Tags: github, pipeline, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server

I have Azure Devops server 2019 update 1.1, I understand from a couple of videos that when we try to create a new pipeline, we should see several options as follows
[image]

whereas on my server, there is no "Githyb Yaml", only enterprise or othergit

[image]

Am I missing a config or an update? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Azure DevOps Server 2019 - Create pipeline - No GitHub yaml option in Where is Your Code

According to the official document [Supported source repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/?view=azure-devops),  Azure Devops server 2019 does not support **GitHub** as Source Repository type even in Classic editor:

[image]

So, there is no GitHub yaml option on the Azure DevOps Server 2019. It is currently only supported by Azure devops services.

Comment: Thanks, how about azure devops 2020, still not supporting it?

Comment: @eliassal, Yes, I verified it on azure devops server 2020 and it is still not supported.